# Is there any folder like hierarchy in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am a new user to Amazon DynamoDB, when I use DynamoDB, I found that I can only create tables, but not databases (Like the databases in MySQL).  

Is there any folder or database like hierarchy system in Amazon DynamoDB, so that I can put a set of tables into one folder (or databases) in order to make the DynamoDB well organized ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Virtually there is no folder in the DynamoDB, Your AWS will have it per account. But you create tables in different regions.

If You are planning to use DynamoDB for multiple applications

1. Create new account (Advantage of this approach is you will get free tier for both the app if account is new)
2. Create tables in different AWS regions (Virtually you can see both the  database in different region)
3. You can create tables for both the apps in same account and same region, in this case, you manually have to know which table belong to which application

Comment: Approach 1 is somewhat impractical and will cause headaches when it comes to using other AWS services, such as CloudWatch, to monitor how your resources are being used, especially if you have more than a couple of applications. Approach 2 will lead to different latencies across different applications and isn't viable if there are more applications than regions. A better approach is one described by @matteo: name your tables according to their purposes, such as "TestUsers", "ProdUsers", etc.

Comment: @PavelSafronov that's what I have mention in third point.. and the question is not about the pros and con of these method... I dont see any reason for down voting..

Answer (score 2):

There is not this kind of hierarchy in DynamoDB itself.
Anyway, if it's suitable for your purpose, you could set up the table name like "$foldername_$tablename". It is quite easy if you manage the tables in an automated manner, but I see it can be a pain if you need to do this manually.

Eg:

```
from boto.dynamodb2 import connect_to_region
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table

users_table = Table(user+'_'+table_name,  # <---this is what I mean
                        connection = connect_to_region(db_region,
                        aws_access_key_id=id,
                        aws_secret_access_key=key))
```